# Prove that subset is dense subset of euclidean line

Tags: general-topology

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be closed set such that $intA=\emptyset$ show that $B =\{t\in \mathbb{R}: \forall q\in \mathbb{Q}-\{0\}, \forall s\in  A, s\neq tq \}$ show that $B$ is dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

I think I need to consider set $C$ such that has elements that are not in $B$ and show $intC=\emptyset$ using baire theorem then we get $B$ is dense but I'm not sure how elements of $C$ will look like I think $C=\{t\in \mathbb{R}: \exists q\in \mathbb{Q}-\{0\}, \exists s\in  A, s= tq \}$ and there I have problem with applying baire theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The complement of $B$ is $\cup \{s A : s\in Q\land s\ne 0\}$ where $s A=\{s x :x\in A\}.$ If $A$ is meager (that is, $int \bar A=\phi$) then so is $s A$. So the complement of $B$ is a countable union of meager sets. The Baire theorem implies that $B$ is dense.